How can I create entry without underline using MAUI?
How can I create entry without underline using MAUI?
<Entry Placeholder="enter your name "/>


Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

The implementation of entry without under line colors for each platform:
On Android:
It's needed to use handler in Android platform. You can add the following code in Platforms -> Android -> MainApplication.cs:
 protected override MauiApp CreateMauiApp()
 {
   Microsoft.Maui.Handlers.EntryHandler.Mapper.AppendToMapping("RemoveUnderLine", (r, v) =>
     {
         r.PlatformView.BackgroundTintList =
             Android.Content.Res.ColorStateList.ValueOf(Colors.Transparent.ToAndroid());
     });

     return MauiProgram.CreateMauiApp();
 }

On Windows:
add the following code in Platforms -> Windows -> App.xaml:
<maui:MauiWinUIApplication.Resources>
        <Thickness x:Key="TextControlBorderThemeThickness">0</Thickness>
        <Thickness x:Key="TextControlBorderThemeThicknessFocused">0</Thickness>
 </maui:MauiWinUIApplication.Resources>

On iOS:
On iOS platform, Entry does not have under line color by default.
